# In Bash, how do I take pairs of files and put them into directories with matching names?

Tags: bash

I have a bunch of files like this (currently all in one directory, but I can separate them by file type or whatever if need be):

```
Pep_1-1.pdb
Pep_1-1.psf
Pep_1-2.pdb
Pep_1-2.psf
Pep_1-3.pdb
...
```

I want to take each pair, make a directory with the corresponding name and then place the two files in that directory (steps don't have to be in this order, I just care about the outcome), so that I have directories like Pep_1-1, Pep_1-2, etc. each containing the two corresponding files. What's the most efficient way to do that?

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you know that it will always follow the structure `Pep_1-#.pdb`?

Comment: Well some will have double digits like Pep_42-38.pdb and Pep_42-38.psf as an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the files always exist in pairs, it's easiest to iterate over one of the pair and extract the name sans extension.

```
for f in *.pdb; do
    basename=${f%.*}
    mkdir "$basename"
    mv "$f" "$basename.psf" "$basename"
done
```

Comment: I would use 'mkdir -p' just to make sure we don't get an error if dir exists already.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sed` and `awk` or use `basename` but I think simple problems should be met with simple solutions. This is why I asked if your files will always be in the form of `Pep_1-#.pdb` and `Pep_1-#.psf`.

Simply build the for loop as follows:

```
for i in `seq 1 50`;
do
    mkdir "Pep_1-$i";
    # Cannot do glob expansion
    cp "Pep_1-$i.pdb" "Pep_1-$i/";
    cp "Pep_1-$i.psf" "Pep_1-$i/";
done
```

Always backup your directories before testing!